# How to check the BIOS version or name in Linux through a command prompt?

Tags: linux, terminal, bios

I want to retrieve the current BIOS version and name while working on the terminal.

What could be the commands to find it?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/392446/how-to-know-the-motherboard-bios-version-using-the-command-line

Answer (score 85, accepted):

BIOS version is exposed through the [SMBIOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_BIOS) tables.  On Linux, we can access this with [`dmidecode`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/dmidecode) (which requires `root` privileges to run).

To show only BIOS information, use `-t bios` to specify that we only want to see entries of the type BIOS, and `-q` to silence unnecessary output.

```
# dmidecode -t bios -q
BIOS Information
        Vendor: Phoenix Technologies LTD
        Version: 6.00
        Release Date: 02/22/2012
        Address: 0xE72C0
        Runtime Size: 101696 bytes
        ROM Size: 64 kB
        Characteristics:
                ISA is supported
                PCI is supported
                ...
        BIOS Revision: 4.6
        Firmware Revision: 0.0
```

To get just the BIOS version information, use `-s` to specify certain strings:

```
# dmidecode -s bios-vendor
Phoenix Technologies LTD
# dmidecode -s bios-version
6.00
# dmidecode -s bios-release-date
02/22/2012
```

Comment: -bash: dmidecode: command not found

Comment: Try installing it with `sudo yum install dmidecode` or `apt-get install dmidecode`.

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功纳米比亚威视 That is why my prompts start with a `#` though - to indicate that I was running as `root`.

Comment: That's just a convention. Explicitly saying so would save at least one full second to lots of people reading this answer. :)

Answer (score 32):

You can also `cat /sys/class/dmi/id/bios_version` without having to run `dmidecode` as root.

`/sys/class/dmi/id` contains also other interesting files:

- bios_date
- bios_vendor
- bios_version
- product_family
- product_name
- product_serial
- product_version

A quick overview of them all can be obtained with

```
head /sys/class/dmi/id/*
```

(I use `head` because it prints the name of the file above the first few lines of the file contents.)

Comment: I like this answer because nothing need be installed to use it.

Comment: You will get errors with this approach like "head: error reading '/sys/class/dmi/id/subsystem': Is a directory"

Comment: No problem with other motherboard...

Answer (score 2):

you can use dmidecode. dmidecode support following operating systems

```
Linux i386, x86-64, ia64
FreeBSD i386, amd64
NetBSD i386, amd64
OpenBSD i386, amd64
BeOS i386
Cygwin i386
Solaris x86
Haiku i586
```

http://www.nongnu.org/dmidecode/